# combine list and custom formula data validation in one cell

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am working on a spreadsheet that will be used to order uniforms.

All the sizes are contained on a separate sheet.

I am trying to use data validation to ensure that whomever inputs a size, only selects from available sizes chosen from a list.

**AND**

that if they have selected a size for one sex, that they cannot input a size from another.

[image: example]

[image: example2]

The issue I'm having is that I can only choose between having a dropdown list or using my custom formula that performs the appropriate checks I need.

**Is there a way to have more than one Data Validation setting per cell or to combine settings?**

My custom formula: `=AND((SYSVAR!$G$3:$G$45), ISBLANK(J9))`

Comment: Since you have separate columns for men's items and other for women's, just have the Data Validation for the applicable sizes in each appropriate column, why do you need an error check?

Comment: I just want to ensure I only get one pair of data

Comment: So basically you only want the user to be able to fill either the Men's Size or the Women's size, but not both?  Why not change your order form to have a drop down for sex (M/F) -> drop down for clothing type (Trousers, Coat) -> drop down for size (appropriate sizes based on sex and clothing type, can use data validation if necessary).  This ensures that they can only select a single sex per line item on the order form.

Comment: Would that be called a dependent list? Sorry, I'm new to all this.

Comment: In the data validation list formula you can use nested if's to select values in another range.  It would be simpler as tigeravatar suggested to have one column for gender, another column for coat/trousers.  This formula is based on that concept.
=IF(B2&LEFT(C2,1)="MC",$I$2:$I$4,IF(B2&LEFT(C2,1)="MT",$I$5:$I$7,IF(B2&LEFT(C2,1)="FC",$I$8:$I$10,$I$11:$I$13)))    Gender is in column B, Coat Trouser is in column C (with their own validation) and the valid values are in column I, with three options for each validation.